# Child component is not rendering props

Tags: reactjs

I got a problem *ChildComponent* is not rendering data with map function, although console.log(data) prints the data every time I fetch APIs with a click in *MainComponent*.

On a click MainComponent should fetch APIs for all episodes for each character of Rick and Morty. handleClick method fetches multiple APIs, may be I am calling them wrong? Props are being updated with each click I can see it, but data is not rendered.

```
class MainComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { actors: [], episodes: [] };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(arr) {
    const dataEpisodes = [];
    arr.map((api) =>
      axios.get(api).then((response) => dataEpisodes.push(response.data.name))
    );
    this.setState({ episodes: dataEpisodes });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
      .then((response) => this.setState({ actors: response.data.results }));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.episodes);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row g-3">
          <div className="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
            <ChildComponent episodes={this.state.episodes} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7 col-lg-8 ">
            <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
              {this.state.actors.map((actor) => (
                <div key={actor.id} className="col m-3">
                  <div className="card shadow-sm">
                    <img
                      className="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top"
                      width="100%"
                      height="225"
                      src={actor.image}
                      role="img"
                      aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"
                      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
                      focusable="false"
                    />

                    <div className="card-body">
                      <h1 className="card-text">{actor.name}</h1>
                      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div className="btn-group">
                          <button
                            onClick={() => this.handleClick(actor.episode)}
                            type="button"
                            className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
                          >
                            Episodes
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <small className="text-muted">{actor.species}</small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainComponent;
```

and this is my ChildComponent

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  const data = props.episodes;
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Episodes</h1>
      {data.map((i) => (
        <h6>{i}</h6>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API calls are async and you need to wait for them to complete before setting the state. The correct way to implement the fetch call is to make use of `Promise.all` which waits for all promises to resolve.

```
handleClick(arr) {
    const dataEpisodes = [];
    const promises = arr.map((api) =>
      axios.get(api).then((response) => response.data.name)
    );
    Promise.all(promises).then(dataEpisodes => this.setState({ episodes: dataEpisodes }));
    
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it a right way to loop through APIs and call them and then setState? The way it is done now?

Comment: From within the map you are returning promises, which are then passed on to Promise.all. That is the correct way to update data obtained from multiple api calls. Please do check the documentation of Promise.all and read on how promise chain works